# Django - TypeError at /uploaddd unhashable type: 'dict'

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to return the document object as json when I hit the function upload. I'm getting the following error

> TypeError at /uploaddd unhashable type: 'dict'

This is the function

```
def uploaddd(request):
    documents = {
        {
            "@search.action": "upload",
            "HotelId": "1",
            "HotelName": "Secret Point Motel 2020",
            "Description": "The hotel is ideally located on the main commercial artery of the city in the heart of New York. A few minutes away is Time's Square and the historic centre of the city, as well as other places of interest that make New York one of America's most attractive and cosmopolitan cities.",
            "Description_fr": "L'hôtel est idéalement situé sur la principale artère commerciale de la ville en plein cœur de New York. A quelques minutes se trouve la place du temps et le centre historique de la ville, ainsi que d'autres lieux d'intérêt qui font de New York l'une des villes les plus attractives et cosmopolites de l'Amérique.",
            "Category": "Boutique",
            "Tags": [ "pool", "air conditioning", "concierge" ],
            "ParkingIncluded": "false",
            "LastRenovationDate": "1970-01-18T00:00:00Z",
            "Rating": 3.60,
            "Address": {
                "StreetAddress": "677 5th Ave",
                "City": "New York",
                "StateProvince": "NY",
                "PostalCode": "10022",
                "Country": "USA"
            }
        },
    
    }    
    return JsonResponse({'doc': documents })
```

The issue is the latest entry the the object    "Country": "USA"

Any ideas?

EDIT - This is showing multiple documents being including in the object.

```
def uploaddd(request):
    documents = {
        {
            "@search.action": "upload",
            "HotelId": "1",
            "HotelName": "Secret Point Motel 2020",
            "Description": "The hotel is ideally located on the main commercial artery of the city in the heart of New York. A few minutes away is Time's Square and the historic centre of the city, as well as other places of interest that make New York one of America's most attractive and cosmopolitan cities.",
            "Description_fr": "L'hôtel est idéalement situé sur la principale artère commerciale de la ville en plein cœur de New York. A quelques minutes se trouve la place du temps et le centre historique de la ville, ainsi que d'autres lieux d'intérêt qui font de New York l'une des villes les plus attractives et cosmopolites de l'Amérique.",
            "Category": "Boutique",
            "Tags": [ "pool", "air conditioning", "concierge" ],
            "ParkingIncluded": "false",
            "LastRenovationDate": "1970-01-18T00:00:00Z",
            "Rating": 3.60,
            "Address": {
                "StreetAddress": "677 5th Ave",
                "City": "New York",
                "StateProvince": "NY",
                "PostalCode": "10022",
                "Country": "USA"
            }
        },
        {
            "@search.action": "upload",
            "HotelId": "2",
            "HotelName": "Twin Dome Motel",
            "Description": "The hotel is situated in a  nineteenth century plaza, which has been expanded and renovated to the highest architectural standards to create a modern, functional and first-class hotel in which art and unique historical elements coexist with the most modern comforts.",
            "Description_fr": "L'hôtel est situé dans une place du XIXe siècle, qui a été agrandie et rénovée aux plus hautes normes architecturales pour créer un hôtel moderne, fonctionnel et de première classe dans lequel l'art et les éléments historiques uniques coexistent avec le confort le plus moderne.",
            "Category": "Boutique",
            "Tags": [ "pool", "free wifi", "concierge" ],
            "ParkingIncluded": "false",
            "LastRenovationDate": "1979-02-18T00:00:00Z",
            "Rating": 3.60,
            "Address": {
                "StreetAddress": "140 University Town Center Dr",
                "City": "Sarasota",
                "StateProvince": "FL",
                "PostalCode": "34243",
                "Country": "USA"
                }
        },
    }   
    return JsonResponse({'doc': documents })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a mistake in empty {}

````
documents = {
        "@search.action": "upload",
        "HotelId": "1",
        "HotelName": "Secret Point Motel 2020",
        "Description": "The hotel is ideally located on the main commercial artery of the city in the heart of New York. A few minutes away is Time's Square and the historic centre of the city, as well as other places of interest that make New York one of America's most attractive and cosmopolitan cities.",
        "Description_fr": "L'hôtel est idéalement situé sur la principale artère commerciale de la ville en plein cœur de New York. A quelques minutes se trouve la place du temps et le centre historique de la ville, ainsi que d'autres lieux d'intérêt qui font de New York l'une des villes les plus attractives et cosmopolites de l'Amérique.",
        "Category": "Boutique",
        "Tags": ["pool", "air conditioning", "concierge"],
        "ParkingIncluded": "false",
        "LastRenovationDate": "1970-01-18T00:00:00Z",
        "Rating": 3.60,
        "Address": {
            "StreetAddress": "677 5th Ave",
            "City": "New York",
            "StateProvince": "NY",
            "PostalCode": "10022",
            "Country": "USA"
        }
    }
    # Mistake
    documents = {
        { #<- mistake
            "@search.action": "upload",
            "HotelId": "1",
            "HotelName": "Secret Point Motel 2020",
            "Description": "The hotel is ideally located on the main commercial artery of the city in the heart of New York. A few minutes away is Time's Square and the historic centre of the city, as well as other places of interest that make New York one of America's most attractive and cosmopolitan cities.",
            "Description_fr": "L'hôtel est idéalement situé sur la principale artère commerciale de la ville en plein cœur de New York. A quelques minutes se trouve la place du temps et le centre historique de la ville, ainsi que d'autres lieux d'intérêt qui font de New York l'une des villes les plus attractives et cosmopolites de l'Amérique.",
            "Category": "Boutique",
            "Tags": [ "pool", "air conditioning", "concierge" ],
            "ParkingIncluded": "false",
            "LastRenovationDate": "1970-01-18T00:00:00Z",
            "Rating": 3.60,
            "Address": {
                "StreetAddress": "677 5th Ave",
                "City": "New York",
                "StateProvince": "NY",
                "PostalCode": "10022",
                "Country": "USA"
            }
        }, #<- mistake
    ```
    if you want store many dicts:
    ```
    documents = [
        {
            "@search.action": "upload",
            "HotelId": "1",
            "HotelName": "Secret Point Motel 2020",
            "Description": "The hotel is ideally located on the main commercial artery of the city in the heart of New York. A few minutes away is Time's Square and the historic centre of the city, as well as other places of interest that make New York one of America's most attractive and cosmopolitan cities.",
            "Description_fr": "L'hôtel est idéalement situé sur la principale artère commerciale de la ville en plein cœur de New York. A quelques minutes se trouve la place du temps et le centre historique de la ville, ainsi que d'autres lieux d'intérêt qui font de New York l'une des villes les plus attractives et cosmopolites de l'Amérique.",
            "Category": "Boutique",
            "Tags": [ "pool", "air conditioning", "concierge" ],
            "ParkingIncluded": "false",
            "LastRenovationDate": "1970-01-18T00:00:00Z",
            "Rating": 3.60,
            "Address": {
                "StreetAddress": "677 5th Ave",
                "City": "New York",
                "StateProvince": "NY",
                "PostalCode": "10022",
                "Country": "USA"
            }
        },
        {
            "@search.action": "upload",
            "HotelId": "2",
            "HotelName": "Twin Dome Motel",
            "Description": "The hotel is situated in a  nineteenth century plaza, which has been expanded and renovated to the highest architectural standards to create a modern, functional and first-class hotel in which art and unique historical elements coexist with the most modern comforts.",
            "Description_fr": "L'hôtel est situé dans une place du XIXe siècle, qui a été agrandie et rénovée aux plus hautes normes architecturales pour créer un hôtel moderne, fonctionnel et de première classe dans lequel l'art et les éléments historiques uniques coexistent avec le confort le plus moderne.",
            "Category": "Boutique",
            "Tags": [ "pool", "free wifi", "concierge" ],
            "ParkingIncluded": "false",
            "LastRenovationDate": "1979-02-18T00:00:00Z",
            "Rating": 3.60,
            "Address": {
                "StreetAddress": "140 University Town Center Dr",
                "City": "Sarasota",
                "StateProvince": "FL",
                "PostalCode": "34243",
                "Country": "USA"
                }
        },
    ]
    ```
````

Comment: If I have multiple objects in the document, I get the error back. Like my edit, i have two documents

Comment: You can't add value in dict without key. In your case it {{'some_key': ['data']}}

Comment: But I'm not? I'm just adding documents to an object

Comment: please check my answer, I added some examples for you and what is wrong in your code